# Kotlin. Expecting when-condition. How to fix?

Tags: kotlin

I am writing a kotlin parser library and faced the following problem.

My code

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
val test = "jap"
val url = when (test) {
    "jap" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=10",
    "cor" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=11",
    "chi" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=12",
    "eng" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=13",
    "rus" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=14",
    "fan" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=15",
    "all" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list",
    else -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=10"
}
println(url)

}
```

Err message

```
compiler.kotlin:11:62: error: expecting a when-condition
    "jap" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=10",
                                                         ^
compiler.kotlin:12:62: error: expecting a when-condition
    "cor" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=11",
                                                         ^
etc.
```

how can i solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to remove commas inside the [`when` expression](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kotlin-when-expression/):

```kotlin
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val test = "jap"
    val url = when (test) {
        "jap" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=10"
        "cor" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=11"
        "chi" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=12"
        "eng" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=13"
        "rus" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=14"
        "fan" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=15"
        "all" -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list"
        else -> "https://staticlib.me/manga-list?types[]=10"
    }
    println(url)
}
```

You can also improve your code as follows:

```kotlin
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val test = "jap"
    var url = "https://staticlib.me/manga-list"
    if (test != "all") url += "?types[]=" + when (test) {
        "jap" -> "10"
        "cor" -> "11"
        "chi" -> "12"
        "eng" -> "13"
        "rus" -> "14"
        "fan" -> "15"
        else  -> "10"
    }
    println(url)
}
```

---

**EDIT**

As suggested by [gidds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10134209/gidds) in the comments, here is another way to improve the code:

```kotlin
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val test = "jap"
    val types = when (test) {
        "jap" -> "10"
        "cor" -> "11"
        "chi" -> "12"
        "eng" -> "13"
        "rus" -> "14"
        "fan" -> "15"
        "all" -> null
        else  -> "10"
    }
    val url = "https://staticlib.me/manga-list" + types?.let{ "?types[]=$it" }
    println(url)
}
```

Comment: You could probably improve it even further: have the `when` return a string (or null for "all"), store that in a `types` variable, and then construct the URL based on that, e.g. `val url = "…" + types?.let{ "?types[]=$it" }`. Should be more readable, and keep all the recognised strings inside the `when`. — For better performance, replace the `when` with a Map called `types` instead.

Comment: @gidds thank you, I've added your version as well.